# How to Update one tables value with another tables value by joining them?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one question, can you please help me out?

Below is the update statement I have written and my requirement is to update ABC table with the value of XYZ(old_qty with the new_qty and old_consumed_qty with the new_consumed_qty). I want to update this by joining these two tables only. My query is not working, and it is giving ORA-01779 cannot modify a column which maps to a non key preserved table.

Note: I am rigid about joining these tables(ABC, XYZ) because NEEDDATE is in monthly level in my cursor(pl/sql block) but I have to update it in daily level and daily level data is present in XYZ table.

I tried with this query:

```sql
update
    (Select fc.item, fc.loc, fc.needdate,fc.qty old_qty,fco.qty_new new_qty,fc.consumedqty old_consumed_qty,   (fco.custqty-fco.custqty_new) new_consumed_qty
    from fcstorder fc, fcstorder_cons_output fco
    where fc.item=fco.item
    and fc.loc=fco.loc
    and fc.needdate=fco.needdate) t
    set t.old_qty = t.new_qty,
    t.OLD_CONSUMED_QTY = t.new_consumed_qty
```

Comment: Have you tried MERGE ?

Comment: You appear to be trying to write a procedure that uses cursor loops, temporary tables and repeatedly calling `UPDATE` within the loop to modify those temporary tables. That is not a particularly "Oracle" solution and is going to not be very performant (I'd guess that you've come from a non-Oracle RDBMS where that is a "usual" solution) and you would probably be better to re-write the logic so that you can do it without loops and temporary tables and, if possible, in a single SQL statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle does not support that syntax; you can use a `MERGE` statement:

```sql
MERGE INTO fcstorder fc
USING fcstorder_cons_output fco
ON (   fc.item     = fco.item
   AND fc.loc      = fco.loc
   AND fc.needdate = fco.needdate
   )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET consumedqty = fco.custqty-fco.custqty_new,
      qty         = fco.qty_new;
```